# django group by aggregate

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following query set in django

```
query_set = JoineryLabour.objects.filter(quote_no = qt.quote_no).values("Hours", "Aspect", "JoineryID")
```

This gives me the following output

```
|Hours|Aspect|JoineryID
|100  |Load  |123
|50   |Cut   |123
|300  |Load  |123
|50   |Load  |234
```

What I want is that, hours will be added with the same JoineryID and grouped by Aspect. Like the following:

```
|Hours|Aspect|JoineryID
|400  |Load  |123
|50   |Cut   |123
|50   |Load  |234
```

is it possible to do it in query? The aspect list is dynamic and can be long. I can manage to do it if it's of the fixed size, however, the list is dynamic and I am using nested loops for that. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you just wanting to order them? or actually sum the hours per id?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, sum the hours per JoineryID and aspect. So if, JoineryID is 123 and Aspect is Load, I want to sum the hours. If the aspects are Cut, I will sum the cut etc.

Comment: you should try annotate

Comment: Yeah but not sure how to do this in this case, I am performing sum on hours based on the match of both JoineryID and Aspect. @ArpitSolanki

Comment: I could write the raw query, which you (or others) could then translate into django, but I'd need to see sample CREATE and INSERT statements and the corresponding desired result first.